# (C#) ReportViewer in Windows Service

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-services, reportviewer

we have a WPF project witch create some reports (22 exacly) using ReportViewer (2010), all those reports with more than 100 pages and really complex layout. Now we need a Windows Service to create those reports automatic everyday.

I Created the service, using the exaclty same logic, created the installer and build it, but, when I executed, the service only save 14 reports and it throws this exeception:

[image: Win32Exception: Error creating window handle]

```
Win32Exception: Error creating window handle
```

(My VS is in portuguese, here is the translation for you guys:)

I noticed that the use of RAM of the process goes up in a strage way, hitting the 570MB when the exception is called.

I Thought it could be some problem with the logic of creation of reports, so i created a Console Application Project to call the method and it works just fine.

My doubts are:

1) Is it possible have a limit of RAM use for a service, being necessary I clear the memory after every saved report? (if yes, how can I clear the memory? i inclued the call `GC.Collec();` but unsuccessfully)

2) Is it possible that ReportViewer (a Windows.Form Component) enters in conflict with some stuff in Windows Services componenets causing the error?

Best Regards for everyone

Comment: I would guess that using `ReportViewer` in a service app is probably a bad idea. I'm sure there's a better way to generate the reports that doesn't rely on UI components.

Comment: We had a similiar issues due lack of RAM. Using x64 platform may help.

Comment: I agree with @DavidG but it's really necessary update all the reports automatically every day (Boss Orders), I'm not sure if I can change the `ReportViewer` stuff :(

Comment: using x64 platform @Ugur ? Can you explain that please ?

Comment: @GuilhermeGolfetto I mean switching platform from 32bit to 64bit system may help to increase your virtual memory space for your code/programm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To proceed with my needs, I decided to create a Console application and run a batch file to run it at the Windonws Task Scheduler once a day.

Is not the solution for the questions but it solved my situation.